# Runtime.getRuntime().exec - Executing osql query

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am trying to execute a osql command from Java program to restore database as follows.

```
public void restore(){

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start osql -S PC-NAME -U username -P password -i createdb.sql
}
```

When I call method restore, the command prompt gets opened, osql gets executed and then command prompt becomes invisible.

Could you please let me know if there is a way to stop command prompt from gettings closed?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Write your command `osql ...` into a bat file, put `pause` as the last line of that bat file and run that bat from your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. It works with the batch file. Is it not possible to retain the command prompt when we execute directly from Java code?

Comment: @NewBie `cmd` exits when the command passed as `/c` exits. You can combine two commands in one line using `&` and pass the combined command as an argument to `/c`. But I'm not sure about the syntax. Try to call `cmd /c start osql -S PC-NAME -U username -P password -i createdb.sql & pause" (not sure).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start dir");
}
```

and this does not close the command line generated.

From this link http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

```
Options   
   /C     Carries out My_Command and then terminates 
   /K     Carries out My_Command but remains
```

Can you try /K instead of /C and let know what the results are ?

Also you should first try this from a batch file before trying it from Java.